# connect html with javascript Date object

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to build a page that takes the current hour and minute from the javascript date module and then makes the background color unique based off of that info.

what needs to change to get the html liked with the javascript? (new to this if you cant tell).

HTML

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>New color for each minute of day</title>

    </head>

    <body id="body">

    <script src="script.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var body = document.getElementById("body");
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;


function currentTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var hour = today.getHours();
    var minute = today.getMinutes();

    minute = formatTime(minute);

    text.innerHTML = hour + ":" + minute;

    return minute
}

function changeColor() {
    for (minute =< 59; a + 1); 

    for (hour =< 24; b + 10);

}

function setScene() {
    timeValue = currentTime();

}

window.addEventListener("load", initialScene, false);
document.body.style.backgroundColor= 'rgb(' + a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ')';
```

Comment: And what would `text` be inside `currentTime`?

Comment: @ArtjomB. oops was a copy/paste error.

Comment: CSS can't read what's in your JavaScript code (so `a`, `b`, and `c` have no meaning in your CSS). Plus, you wouldn't make a concatenated string for the `background-color` value, you would just make it `background-color: rgb(123, 123, 123);`, where the `123`s are integers between `0` and `255`. It'd probably be easier to have JS apply a specific class to your `body` depending on the time, and then have a set of classes defined in your CSS that will set a different background color for each class (and the JS would end up applying one of those classes).

Comment: @ajp15243 i found a JS fiddle that did it as so... but regardless, how do i improve this so it works?

Comment: @rs202 If you found a JS Fiddle using JS-like logic in CSS, it may have been using a really old IE feature that allowed JavaScript evaluation inside of CSS. That feature has been deprecated, obsolete, and removed for a very long time.

Comment: @ajp15243 and re the classes: wouldnt that mean 59 classes for each miin and then 24 for each hour? is there a more efficient way?

Comment: @rs202 If you want that many classes, then it's probably easier to have JS directly edit the styles instead of applying a class, and to come up with some simple arithmetic in the JS that could dynamically produce the color values from the time. Or if you can't think of any handy arithmetic trick, just make an array of colors or map of times to colors and use the time to dynamically pick your color out of the array/map. It looks like you're already making an arithmetic-based solution with the `for` loops. See @tomysshadow's answer, I think that will get you further along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omit the CSS (style tag) in the first example and just use plain JS.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background="rgb("+a+", "+b+", "+c+");";
```

should do it

That's the main problem. Also, in your changeColor function, you are not using the for loop correctly, although you've got the right idea.

```
for (minute=0;minute<=59;minute+=1) {
a=minute;
}
for (hour=0;hour=<24;hour+=10) {
b=hour;
}
```

for loops can be a confusing subject for newcomers to JS, but there are some great tutorials online. Do a Google Search and really take the time to learn what a for loop does sometime, it's a good thing to know.

PS I don't see where c is defined.

Comment: @rs202 It changes color so probably at the end of `changeColor`.

Comment: It should go after a, b, and c have all been defined. So preferably at the end of your "changeColor" function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you ask for a changing background for every minute of the day. You need to define a recurring function that reads the time and changes the color. You have that as `setScene`.

Now you can call it every 60 seconds automatically by pasting the following somewhere inside `initialScene`:

```
setInterval(setScene, 60000);
```